# Prove that an orthogonal matrix $A$ has the property $A^T A = I$

Tags: matrices, orthogonal-matrices

> Prove that $A^T A = I$ if $A$ is a square matrix with orthonormal columns.

I'm not sure how to approach it, any ideas/hints?

Comment: If $A$ has orthogonal (I presume orthonormal) columns then $(A e_i)^T (A e_j) = \delta_{ij}$.

Comment: Note that $e_i^T I e_j = \delta_{ij}$.

Comment: what do you mean by e? eigenvector?

Comment: $e_1=(1,0,0,..)^T$, $e_2=(0,1,0,...)^T$, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are computing a matrix multiplication, let's say for example, $AB$, to obtain the $(i,j)$-entry of the matrix, you compute the dot product of the $i$-row of $A$ with the $j$-column of $B$.

So, what is the $(i,j)$-entry of $A^tA$ if the columns of $A$ (also the rows of $A^t$) are *orthonormal*?

Comment: oo I think I get it now. Also, just to confirm, if the columns are normalized, then each column's dot product w itself is always 1 right?

Comment: That's right, if they are not normalized then $A^tA$ could be not the identity matrix.